# Generate Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I want to generate an array in jQuery/JS, which contains "code"+[0-9] or [a-z].
So it will look like that.

code0, code1 ..., codeA, codeB

The only working way now is to write them manually and I am sure this is a dumb way and there is a way to generate this automatically.

If you give an answer with a reference to some article where I can learn how to do similar stuff, I would be grateful.

Thank you.

Comment: you could use for loop and array.push()...

Comment: see this post...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4011840/create-dynamic-array-with-jquery

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For **a-z** using the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/) and the JavaScript [fromCharCode()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_fromCharCode.asp) function:

```
var a = [];
for(var i=97; i<=122; i++)
{
  a.push("code" + String.fromCharCode(i));
}
```

For **0-9:**

```
var a = [];
for(var i=0; i<=9; i++)
{
  a.push("code" + i);
}
```

Comment: Define your variables with `var`.

Comment: And your `i` variable too. `for (var i...)`.

Comment: @Mojtaba Thanks again! I'm not an expert in JS, but I try and learn ;-)

Comment: It's also good idea to create a fiddle demo for HTML/CSS/JS answers. Here is the fiddle for your answer: http://jsfiddle.net/mojtaba/8ghkm/

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the unicode hexcode to loop through the whole symbols from 0-z:

```
var arr = [];
for (var i = 0x30; i < 0x7b;i++){
    // skip non word characters
    // without regex, faster, but not as elegant:
    // if(i==0x3a){i=0x41}
    // if(i==0x5b){i=0x61}
    char = String.fromCharCode(i);
    while(!/\w/.test(char)){char = String.fromCharCode(i++)};
    // generate your code
    var res = "code"+char;
    // use your result
    arr.push(res);
}
console.log(arr);
```

Here goes **[your example](http://jsfiddle.net/SyTvx/1/)**.

Docs:

[Unicode Table](http://www.tamasoft.co.jp/en/general-info/unicode.html)
[for loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)
[fromCharCode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/fromCharCode)
[JS Array and it's methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Comment: Thanks for the links. I need to learn more about that stuff. :)

Answer (score 2):

you can generate array in javascript by using following code.

```
var arr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {

    arr.push("code"+ i);
}
```

please refer following links.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array

http://www.scriptingmaster.com/javascript/JavaScript-arrays.asp

Answer (score 1):

```
a = [];
for(i = 48; i < 91; i++) { 
  if (i==58) i = 65
  a.push("code" + String.fromCharCode(i));
}

alert(a.join(',')) // or cou can print to console of browser: console.log(a);
```